# How can I record the link pressed?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image-gallery

(I don't want to add code here because it would be very large chunks that would need explaining.)

To put it simply, I have:

- A page with a 2x2 grid of images on (let's call that images.html),
- A page that is a fullscreen image gallery made using CSS3 and HTML5 (let's call that gallery.html),
- A style sheet that styles aspects of every page in the site except the gallery (let's call that main-styles.css),
- And a style sheet that styles only gallery.html (let's call that gallery-styles.css).

The images in the 2x2 grid (images.html) need to open up the same gallery.html using gallery-styles.css. The only difference should be the range of images the fullscreen gallery displays.

So for one image on images.html, it may display 3 images in gallery.html. But for another image in images.html, it may display 4 entirely different images in gallery.html.

**The problem I am having is how to track the image link that is clicked in images.html so as to display the different range of images in gallery.html.**

The gallery-styles.css has a div that is positioned to be fullscreen, then there is an image list, e.g. '.image1{background-image:url(../images/1.jpg)}' of the different images that can be browsed through (left and right clickable arrows in the gallery.html). The HTML will use each image individually but with the same content holder, e.g.

```
<div class="image-1 holder">
```

How can I go about using the same gallery.html and gallery-styles.css files for each image in images.html? I'm not entirely against JavaScript but have gone this far with just CSS3 and HTML5 would be nice if it was possible to continue that way. Is there possibly a way using the input element?

Any help is great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I think the easiest way for you would be to use [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location#Example_.236.3A_Get_the_value_of_a_single_window.location.search_key.3A). When you click the first image sending you to `gallery.html`, rather than just opening a regular copy, open for example, `gallery.html?image1`. Then in *JavaScript*, you can add this as a *class* to `<body>` or some other node when the page has loaded, and do the rest from *CSS*

```js
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function () {document.body.className += ' '+window.location.search.slice(1)}
);
```

You can now do the decision making using, for example

```css
body > genericNodes {display: none; }
body.image1 > someNode { display: block; }
/* etc */
```

---

A different option for pure *CSS* is to use a *hash* and then [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget), but this means you lose the ability to have anchors in your page. i.e. open `gallery.html#image1` and have

```css
#image1, #image2, #image3, #image4 { display: none; }
:target { display: block !important; }
/* etc */
```

With some nodes of the form

```html
<span id="image1"><!-- contents --></span>
<span id="image2"><!-- contents --></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deal with processing information from the page: client side script (JS) and server side script (PHP or like) unless you have a great number of hand-coded html pages you can load for a corresponding link clicks.

Given that, you either link to your hard-coded page directly from the link, which I assume you have already thought of,

Or, you pass a parameter to server side in a form `http://myserver.asdf/gallery.php?linkid=12&someotherparam=somevalue`

In that case you capture these parameters on server side and generate a page with needed images.
In php all parameters can be found in `$_REQUEST` array.

Does this answer your question?